# Referencing a related object in Pyramids/Python/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

I'm not sure how to title this question. I've also simplified my code so it's easier to ask. Say I have the following code in myproject.models in Pyramid:

```
class Links(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'links'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link = Column(Text)

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link

class Submissions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'submissions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text)
    link_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('links.id'))
    link = relationship(Links)

    def __init__(self, title, link):  
    self.title = title
        self.link = link
```

The view will be very simple:

```
def my_view(request):
    dbsession = DBSession()
    submissions = dbsession.query(Submissions)
    return {'submissions':submissions}
```

I want to return this on my page using Chameleon:

```
<p tal:repeat="thing submissions">
    ${thing.title} ${thing.link}
</p>
```

However, ${thing.link} doesn't show the link of the site.

Questions:

1. How do I reference thing.link's link? Intuitively, I would type ${thing.link.link}, but that doesn't work.
2. How do I reference an arbitrary subclass? I want to be able to extract any attribute from an object's subclass, for example, thing.link.link, thing.link.domain, thing.link.created, etc.

BTW, someone please tell me a better title to give this question.

Comment: I would think ${thing.link.link} would work, and ${thing.link} would at least show *something*.  Are you sure that your submission has a Links object attached, and that the Links object has a link value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are missing the `.all()` after your `.query()`. You can check in your view if your submissions are really loaded by doing something like

```
for submission in submissions:
    print submission.id, submission.title
```

and then watch your console when loading the page.

Then, when you confirmed you really have them loaded, you can access the link object with `submission.link`. In the link object, you can access the link attribute with `.link`.

```
for submission in submissions:
    print submission.link.link
```

So in your template, you could write `${thing.link.link}`.

Comment: I guess it was just the .all(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do have the `link` object attached (given the fact that the `link_id` column is not `nullable`), most probably you need to `(eager)load` the relationship to `Links` because the session is alread closed when you populate your view.
See [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/loading.html?highlight=eager) for more information. The code below should do it:

```
submissions = dbsession.query(Submissions).options(joinedload('link'))
```